# Leaflet Marker render

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw

I now have a map and get the basic of the map from a geoJSON file.

Now i have a websocket and sent always positions from 3 different people. So how can i add a marker , which i can move to another location?

I tried to change `map._layers[*]._latlngs` after adding a marker but it only changes position when i zoom out or move the map.How can i render it by myself, without zooming?

Comment: Use `setLatLng` marker method, see http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker

Comment: same issue....i can modify it but the marker only moves if i zoom out or in..or change map...not immediatly

Comment: Okay...i got it....the update function works on normal markers...so setLatLng and then the same marker update()